# Why does reinitializing an object used in thread synchronization not result in a deadlock?

Tags: java, synchronized

Can someone please explain why the following code will not result in a deadlock?

```
public class Example {
  private static Object object;

  public static synchronized void init() {
    if (object == null) {
      object = new Object();
    } else {
      // do nothing
    }
  }

  public static void doSomething() {
   synchronized (object) {
     // do something
   }
  }

  public static void reinitialize() {
   synchronized (object) {
     try {
       Thread.sleep(5000l);
     }
     catch (Exception e) { }
     object = new Object();
   }
  }
}
```

I wrote the code below with many threads that call the `doSomething` method in a loop and only one thread that calls the `reinitialize` method. I made that thread sleep so it can hold on to the lock and I can see the other threads waiting to resume execution.

```
var threads = IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> new Thread(() -> {
  Example.init();
  for (var count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
    Example.doSomething();
  }
})).toList();

threads.forEach(Thread::start);
new Thread(() -> Example.reinitialize()).start();

threads.forEach(t -> {
  try {
    t.join();
  } catch (Exception e) {});

// The threads do not deadlock and the main method
// finishes executing after all the threads finish
// their work
```

I thought that by reinitializing the `object` variable, the threads that are blocked in the `doSomething` method will be blocked forever because `object` is a different instance.

This is just a learning exercise for me. I would not write code in the `reinitialize` method. Instead, I would have just made the object a constant (`static final`).

Comment: Please show a complete example which illustrates the behaviour.

Comment: No, the threads that are blocked on the old `Object` will unblock when the block that is currently synchronized on it exits. Just like any other time, Changing the object reference inside the synchronized block (or anywhere else) doesn't change what the block is synchronized on. Why you would actually want to do this is another mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we're at a point where method 'reinitialized' is holding the monitor on object-1.  Method 'doSomething' is waiting for the monitor on object-1.

Now we point variable 'object' to object-2.

Method 'reinitialized' is still holding the monitor on object-1.  Method 'doSomething' is still waiting for the monitor on object-1.

Synchronization is based on the object, not the variable.

Nothing else can synchronize on object-1 since it is no longer reachable from any variable.  Any thread that starts a 'synchronized' block after the effect of the assignment becomes visible will sync on object-2.  (There are inherent races in this, so don't do it).